# Users auth and profiles in getstream.io

Tags: getstream-io

I would like to know if I can manage user profiles and user authentication directly with getstream.io?

I had a glance at the samples and I don't understand how the users get created.

Comment: I am also trying same things. did you get solution? If yes Kindly help me. Really trying to implement but not able to finish it. please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's currently not possible to manage user accounts, profiles and auth within Stream.

Stream is best used in combination with an application (e.g. server-side Sails/Node.js, Python/Django, Ruby/Rails etc.) that handles these things and other functionality, application logic and services.

Your application will then have full control and flexibility over which users can read/write and be notified of updates to any particular feed.

Comment: To clarify Dwight's answer further, the user_id you send with the 'actor', as well as the references you send for object, verb, foreign id, don't matter to Stream at all as long as they are unique references that are meaningful to your own application. Typically, the activities you send to Stream are full of reference ids, since the total activity payload maxes out around 1kb of data.