# How to manage user profile authentication in getstream.io?

Tags: node.js, getstream-io

I am a new developer of https://getstream.io/. I am using NodeJS version. I am able to run the example [Example](https://github.com/GetStream/Stream-Example-Nodejs), shows `feed`, `activity`, `notification` and `profile`. Now, I am trying to manage user profile authentication and trying to add a login and registration page with that project but I am unable to do that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Users auth and profils in getstream.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525101/users-auth-and-profils-in-getstream-io)

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a back-end application to manage the connection between your front-end and the Stream API.

Then, after [creating a user](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#users_create), just [get the user's token](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#setup) (using the `createUserToken` function.

When you [create a user](https://getstream.io/docs/js/#users_create), you can pass the password information in the data object and when you create an endpoint for authentication (ie: retrieving the user's token) don't forget to remove this information from the response.

Hope it helps =)